# load big file without current scope / process php

Tags: php, exec, fopen

i need download big file from another server, and save him to file.

how can run script in background? if run in script, my script is suspended.

I try pnctl_fork, exec(), popen(), fopen().

Any function caouses suspended server for current user which asks for the file. Users from another computers have access.

I do not know what's going on.

can anyone help me? sorry for my english..

Comment: On linux servers you can use `cron` to run long-running PHP script. Powodzenia

Comment: Can I run a cron job more frequently than for every minute?

Comment: No, but your script can run longer. Perheps there are some time restriction but one of my script was running more than 1.5h / Nie, ale skryt może działać bardzo długo. Jeden z moich skryptów wykonywał swoją robotę przez 1.5h i nie został wcześniej zakończony.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an idea the way I do it:

1. Queue up any download (have some kind of interface where you queue downloads)
2. set up cronjob that will run and do download on the background every minute or so.

Also have some kind of flags to keep track of statuses of each download. This way your script will not halt while downloading.

Comment: Can I run a cron job more frequently than for every minute?

Comment: wouldnt be great, why 1 minute is not frequent enough ? every minute cronjob will execute all queued jobs.

Comment: I need download file for user if he asked for movie in player, but file is anotherserver. Need start download this file and show for user in player.

Comment: Maybe you need something different - some media server. Or you have to redirect video stream directly to player from another server.